# Django how to set main page

Tags: django, indexing, set, program-entry-point

i want to set a main page or an index page for my app.
i tried adding MAIN_PAGE in settings.py and then creating a main_page view returning a main_page object, but it doesn't work
Also, i tries to add in the urls.py a declaration like

```
(r'^$', index),
```

where indexshould be the name of the index.html file on the root (but it obviously does not work)

What is the best way to set a main page in a Django website?

thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to refer to a static page (not have it go through any dynamic processing), you can use the `direct_to_template` view function from `django.views.generic.simple`. In your URL conf:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
urlpatterns += patterns("",
    (r"^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"})
)
```

(Assuming `index.html` is at the root of one of your template directories.)

Comment: This solution has been deprecated. See the chosen answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428427/no-module-named-simple-error-in-django

Comment: Preferred way of doing this is explained in below answer by ryanjdillon

Answer (score 20):

The new preferred way of doing this would be to use the `TemplateView` class. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005733/moving-from-direct-to-template-to-new-templateview-in-django) if you would like to move from `direct_to_template`.

In your main `urls.py` file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # the regex ^$ matches empty
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='static_pages/index.html'),
        name='home'),
]
```

Note, I choose to put any static pages linke `index.html` in its own directory `static_pages/` within the `templates/` directory.

Comment: It is not clear what the path to `static_pages/index.html` is here. I can't replicate this, it gives 'Template not found' errors.

Comment: I solved the issue by 1) setting `app_name = 'myapp'` in the main `urls.py`, 2) adding `myapp` to the `INSTALLED_APPS` in the main `settings.py`, 3) putting my template at `myapp/templates/myapp/index.html`, 4) updating the view to use `template_name = 'myapp/index.html'`

Answer (score 10):

In case someone searching for an updated version of the answer..

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

and in your `views.py`

```
def index(req):
    return render(req, 'myApp/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the generic [`direct_to_template`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-direct-to-template) view function:

```
# in your urls.py ...
...
url(r'^faq/$', 
    'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', 
    { 'template': 'faq.html' }, name='faq'),
...
```